# Can I express an IFML model in pure XML?

Tags: xml, mda

The wikipedia page about IFML says the standard includes a XML definition to express the modeling. Unfortunately, I have not found any information about this XML representation of an IFML schema, even on the official Web Site.

Does anyone know where we can find this?

Answer (score 0):

You can download xmi file [IFML metamodel](https://www.omg.org/spec/IFML/20140301/IFML-Metamodel.xmi). Then use Eclipse to convert it to xsd. 
It will require several steps. First, you need to convert xmi (UML Model) to ecore file, then create genmodel for the ecore, and finally generate xsd files using genmodel file.